# How to use python to update Microsoft Active Directory password without ssl certificate

Tags: python, active-directory, ldap

I want to use python to manage my company's Active Directory.
but it was establish without ssl certificate.
i use the python lib "ldap3"
use the function "extend.microsoft.modify_password()"
this raise an expection "unwillingToPerform"

Comment: Can you share the relevant code where you're encountering the error?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Python, but I know Active Directory. Whenever I've seen an "unwilling to perform" error, it usually means you're doing something wrong. Either your giving it the wrong (or malformed) distinguished name, or you're giving it the wrong old password. Maybe something else. If you show your code we might be able to help more.

Comment: but my dn is an administrator account

Comment: That's fine, but there may be something wrong with how you entered it. I can't really help much more without seeing your code.

Answer (score 0):

You need a TLS secured connection for changing passwords via LDAP. It cannot be done with a cleartext connection.